# Is there a more elegant/quick way of saving all input-field cookies?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm working on a huge web application that's primarily used by administrators who are interested in looking at statistics. Because of this, there are 20-25 tables with massive filters. The customers want their cookies to be stored for each session, because some of the filters they use are quite intricate and annoying to recreate.

Now before you start typing: I already know how to apply **sessionStorage**, as I've had to use it recently. However, my way of doing it is not very elegant. Here's an example:

```
var fnrCookie = '';
sessionStorage.setItem("fnrCookie", fnr);
var fnrInUse = sessionStorage.getItem("fnrCookie");
```

This represents a single input field in the code. If I'm going to follow the same approach with the rest of the application, then it becomes a very big and mundane task, as there are probably 250-300 input fields combined.

So, is there a way for me to tell my jsp-page to store session cookies for *all* input fields, without having to write a variable for all of them?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently so I stored all the form elements into a single object, json'ed the result and stored into localStorage

```
    //--- process the form elements
   //--- get the second form details (more than one form on the page)
   var f = document.querySelectorAll('form')[1];
   //--- create a new form data object
   fd = new FormData( f );
   //--- iterate over the data
   for( pair of fd.entries() ) {
      //--- handle multiple values on same input name
      x = fd.getAll( pair[0]);
      //--- store values in with input name and it's value
      res[pair[0]] = x.join('~');
   }
    //--- json the whole thing
    x = JSON.stringify(res);
   //--- store it
   localStorage.setItem("formInfo", x );
```